# How to schedule a worker for a time in an specific Time zone in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, utc

I have a form with three fields:

1. Date
2. Time
3. Time zone

Users would like to schedule a task for his customers in another country, that means, in another time zone. So, he will fill the form telling:

`I want this task to be executed at 12/08/2015, at 15:00 in London time zone`

I have these three params and I don't mind where the user is at this moment or where is he from. I just want to transform this three fields information in an UTC date.

**How can I transform this fields in an unique UTC date?**

Comment: Will the input always have this exact format?  Do you mean he is filling in a text field?  It would be better to have three selects, or a javascript datetime picker + a timezone select.

Comment: The form is composed by three selects, yes. I didn't explain this because I considered that it was not relevant to answer the question

Comment: It's totally relevant!  Building a UTC time from three parameters is very different (and easier) to building it from a complete sentence like you gave in your question.

Comment: My apologies, maybe the question was not clear.  Here a deeply explanation: the question is not to focus on the frontend side. Just wanted to make know that there are three fields, in a valid context and in the best format. The question is about how to transform a valid [date, hour, time_zone] fields into an UTC date. I mean, is a backend question. The text I highlighted should be considered just an example of "user story".

Comment: It would be better to just show the parameters in your question: it's more relevant to your actual problem and it saves time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explicitly get a specific `TimeZone` instance, use [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone::[]`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-5B-5D) and call [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone#parse`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse) to create a `TimeWithZone` instance within that timezone:

```
time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['London'].parse('12/08/2015 15:00')
#=> Wed, 12 Aug 2015 15:00:00 BST +01:00
```

or using [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone#local`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-local):

```
time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['London'].local(2015, 8, 12, 15, 0)
#=> Wed, 12 Aug 2015 15:00:00 BST +01:00
```

Calling [`TimeWithZone#utc`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-utc) returns a `Time` instance in UTC:

```
time.utc
# => 2015-08-12 14:00:00 UTC
```

ActiveSupport also provides [`Time::use_zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-use_zone) to set `Time.zone` inside a block:

```
Time.use_zone('London') { Time.zone.parse('12/08/2015 15:00') }
#=> Wed, 12 Aug 2015 15:00:00 BST +01:00
```

Note that ActiveRecord automatically saves DATETIME fields in UTC, so there's usually no need to convert the time to UTC.

Answer (score 2):

Also this method next, it doesn't depend on ActiveSupport.

```
Time.zone = time_zone
time_to_utc = Time.zone.parse('time').utc
```

for example:

```
Time.zone = "London"
time_to_utc = Time.zone.parse('08/07/2015 00:00').utc
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: [`Time.zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone) and [`Time.zone=`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone-3D) are ActiveSupport methods.

Comment: Yup.. `Time.zone` is a `ActiveSupport` method which does read and write.

Answer (score 1):

`Time.use_zone('London') { Time.zone.parse('07/08/2015 17:00') }.utc`

Even this works as expected with single line.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Pacific Time (US & Canada)'].parse(params[:created_at])`

this will work, I think.